# installing xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

I want to  intall xdebug on my wamp server.for find current xdebug for my i  wamp have gone in this website.

[http://xdebug.org/wizard.php][1]

On this site i have pasted my source code of phpinfo and when i submit it will produce the folowing message.

**The compiler (MS VC6) that this PHP was build with, is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a version that was built with MS VC9.**

so whats the issue here? xdebug will not work on my wamp?

I would appreciate any type of help.

Comment: I think all are on the holiday.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match the "build" of PHP extensions to the "build" of PHP...

You are using an older PHP version that was compiled with VC6 (Visual C++ edition from 1998). Probably PHP 5.2.

PHP 5.3 and up are now built exclusively with VC9 (VS.NET 2008).

And XDebug is now only provided as a VC9 build.

You need to update to a newer WAMP version that has at least PHP 5.3 - [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) - [Wamp-Developer Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) - [UniformServer](http://www.uniformserver.com/) -
[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)